# Create splash page for prestashop

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

I'm trying to load a splash page with a logo before the main store page is loaded. I named my page `index.html` and I changed `DirectoryIndex` in `.htaccess` in order to load `index.html` before `index.php`.

The problem is that the card module does no longer work, because it requests a redirect to the main store (`index.php`). In my case it's modified to `index.html` so it gives me a blank page. How can I set up a splash page without causing this problem?

Comment: What's in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I have added this line  `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

Comment: DirectoryIndex will only check in order when you are requesting the root of the directory in question. Unfortunately, I won't be able to answer your question without more information. The only thing I can suggest is that you [check the referring page using `mod_rewrite`](https://unix4lyfe.org/mod_rewrite-on-referer/).

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue for implementing the intro page for prestashop v 1.6
the solution is:
in .htaccess file just add below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html
</IfModule>
```

be careful, the RewriteRule must set to index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

therefore:

-whenever going to [www.sitename.com](http://www.sitename.com) first index.html(intro page) has been shown

-then user can go to other part of prestashop site by any link

-then whenever click on home page, user return to intro page(if you want to back in
prestashop main page NOT in intro page, follow [this link](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/86289-solved-how-to-add-an-html-splash-page))